# Install Scala on Linux without administrator permisisons

Tags: scala, installation, administrator

Instructions to install Scala on Linux are [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_environment_setup.htm), but this requires administrator permissions.

I am working in a shared environment without admin access. Can I install Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, just install it in your home directory. Download the .tgz file from here:

http://www.scala-lang.org/download/

then run `tar xzf scala-[version].tgz`

That will create a directory with an installation of scala. Set your environment variables accordingly (e.g. `$SCALA_HOME` to the directory you just uncompressed, and add the bin subdirectory to `$PATH`)/

Comment: For simplicity's sake, http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path is the link for setting your environment variables

Answer (score 2):

Even better than manual installation would be using some build tool with dependency management, like [SBT](http://scala-sbt.org/) or Maven with [scala-maven-plugin](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/index.html). Sure, you will need Internet connection for them more often if you just used tarball distribution, but if the connection is not a problem then using build tools is much more convenient than manual installation.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have sbt installed either, so that would be a manual install as well.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but installing SBT will also give you whole project management and dependency downloading, but installing Scala will give you, well, only Scala :)